# Novel about people playing a tabletop RPG getting pulled inside

Tags: story-identification, novel

A novel about people playing a tabletop RPG get pulled into the world. They have gauntlets on their arms with dice that roll for outcomes. One character was a berserker type and he had a small flying dragon with him.

Comment: Hiya, I just want to back up what FuzzyBoots has said- this question will be easier to answer if you ask it separately, as two questions. Also, to save you a step later, any more details you have might make the difference in someone finding an answer. Were the books in English? When did you read them? Were they appropriate for young people, or just adults? Do you remember cover art or anything similar?

Comment: The RPG pulled into another world book gets asked about once a month it seems - almost certainly a dupe. Wonder if we could just pin that and the one about getting sucked into another world via PC game to the home screen.... :D - came here to vtc but will leave open to allow for edit

Comment: @kelloggd If you want the second question answered, paste your description into another question:                                                                     "A story about a man looking to lose weight. He taps into something primal, not only losing weight but changing, becoming stronger and faster. But he continues to change, growing more aggressive. There was a scene about him fighting a master with fighting sticks."

Comment: Not too broad anymore

Comment: Also see Jumanji.

Comment: Apologies and thanks to everyone for the tips. Unfortunately, these are books I read when I was a kid and after 30+ years the details I have are very limited but will include what I can. Thankfully I someone was able to figure out the first one with the limited detail. I am surprised and thankful as there was very little I could remember but it is one of those questions that continued to plague me. Again, sorry for the errors in posting and thanks to everyone for the responded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The book you describe is one of Andre Norton's worst books (and the very first Dungeons and Dragons novel so far as I know), [*Quag Keep*.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/662286.Quag_Keep)

> Once, they were role-playing gamers in our world.
>   They came from different places and different backgrounds.
>   Now they're summoned together by some magical force...to a land that mirrors the games they used to play.
>   Quag Keep. 
>   Can they band together to unlock the secret of their summoning--and rescue from the legendary Quag Keep the person who may be able to return them home?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andre_Norton _"In 1976, Gary Gygax invited Norton to play Dungeons & Dragons in his Greyhawk world. Norton subsequently wrote Quag Keep, which involved a group of characters who travel from the real world to Greyhawk. It was the first novel to be set, at least partially, in the Greyhawk setting and, according to Alternative Worlds, the first to be based on D&D."_

Comment: If it's that, this is also [a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75582/classic-fantasy-with-characters-from-the-real-world/75583#75583)

Comment: That is the one. Thank you.

Comment: @kelloggd: You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Done. Thank you.